# Spring Social - How to Redirect to original URL or authenticate via Popup/Iframe with reload

Tags: javascript, spring, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, spring-social

I have a web application which uses spring security with spring social integration. I have placed sign-in button (form post) on the menu of the application which can be accessed from any of the paths/webpages. I am able to sign-in by posting on /signin/{provider} from my webpage which redirects to google's login page for authentication and upon successful authentication redirects back to a **"configured URL"**. I want this URL to be dynamic so the user is redirected back to original URL where the user clicked on **Sign In With Google** button.

Options I have:

1. Use [SignInAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/connect/web/SignInAdapter.html) to return the URL to be redirected to. We get the native web request object here in signIn() method but I am not able to find a way to send some parameter say, callback url, during initial signin form post which may become available in signIn() method.
2. Upon FormPost, instead of redirecting in the same window, open an iframe/popup to handle the post response (which is actually the providers url like http://accounts.google.com/......). And after successful authentication reload the parent page. But here iframe does not allow cross domain urls. For popups, I don't know how to bring form post response in a popup.

This is an e-commerce application so want to strive for some best practices in terms of security and users constraints (like blocked popus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working with second approach mentioned in the question. Instead of doing sign in form post (signin/{providerId}) directly on click of "Login with Google" button, open a popup window (child window) with something like :

```
<button type="submit" onClick=
"window.open('/signin?formId=googleForm','Ratting','width=550,height=400,left=150,top=200,toolbar=0,status=0,');" class="googlelogin" style="border-width: 0px;">
</button>
```

and on this popup window, through javascript, do an auto form post during onload.

Configure the redirect url, which loads after succesful signin, to a page which has a javascript code which reloads your parent window. Something like:

```
(function(){
    if (opener) {
      opener.postMessage("reload", '*');
      window.close();
    }
    else {
        window.location.assign('/');
    }
}());
```

The parent window should have a listener for message posted by child window. Something like:

```
function listener(event){
    if (event.data === "reload")
        document.location.reload();
}
if (window.addEventListener){
  addEventListener("message", listener, false)
} else {
  attachEvent("onmessage", listener)
}
```

Hope it helps someone looking for the solution to a very trivial use case like this.