# Iframe google login - refresh iframe after login

Tags: javascript, authentication, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I am making google extension that displays iframe with my website.
Website in iframe have Google login button and I need to do this:

**After you click login button, you get popup with login**

```
<a href="GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL_OAUTH2" target="popup" 
  onclick="window.open('GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL_OAUTH2','popup','width=200,height=200'); return false;">
    Login with google
</a>
```

Got it

**After successful login I need refresh iframe** -> You'll be logged inside iframe

I tried this [Spring Social - How to Redirect to original URL or authenticate via Popup/Iframe with reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342629/spring-social-how-to-redirect-to-original-url-or-authenticate-via-popup-iframe) but it don't work for iframe

And I can't make login in new window because it won't refresh iframe

(sorry for trivial question, i am totally noob at JS/jQuery)
Thanks for replay.

Comment: you cant put the google login an iframe, it needs to be in a new browser window so the user can see the url in the bar and know its not some dummy scammer pretending to be a google login page..

Comment: Ye, thats why I have popup window. I know you can't put google login into iframe.
But i need refresh my iframe when is login complete